Android Studio hangs opening Flutter project
While having an old project open, I created a new Flutter project (File/New/New Flutter project...). Now, Android Studio hangs at this dialog:

Clicking the Cancel button does nothing. CPU time of Android Studio is <0.3%. The main window can be resized, but the client area does not repaint. Once the window is made smaller than the loading dialog, the loading dialog also disappears.
I am using Android Studio 2024.2.1, installed via the Jetbrains Toolbox, if that matters. I just uninstalled an older version today (2023.x) and installed the new version afterwards.
What could I do in order to get Android Studio working again?
I have tried:

updaing everything (plugins, SDK, ...)


I could create the new project by closing the existing project first (File/Close Project), and then select "New Flutter project" from the Android Studio Start Screen.

